# Cannot replicate font sharpness

Tags: css, fonts, polymer

I am trying to rebuild this website in Polymer: http://qprogrammers-mockup.webflow.io/. So I can extend it easily in the future. I have everything down and I am using the same font, font-weight, font-size and I checked this with a chrome extension whatfont?.

But the fonts seems different. The example website is still much sharper. I read the css, but I cannot find out why. I also added:

```
body {
    background-color: e8e8e8;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, I cannot tell how much more CSS you have. But this may just be a case of you not invoking the webfont Open Sans and your browser is reverting to whichever sans-serif it is using. You could add the following line to the top of your CSS and see if it makes a difference:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
```

Finally, you are missing a '#' on your background color property:

```
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
```